# Flash 3D Navigation Wall

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to create a 3D navigation wall similar to http://www.dior.com/couture/en_us/The-House-of-Dior/THE-HOUSE-OF-DIOR.

I've seen a similar plugin in http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/3dwall/.

However, I want to create it from scratch as I need to customize it very much.

Any starting template you know would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A template might be helpful, but if you truly need to customize it very much, I would suggest that you learn the ins and outs of a nice 3D code library. If you do find a template, you will probably spend just as much time tweaking it only to find that it doesn't allow for what you want.

There are many existing 3D libraries for ActionScript that could make this a pretty straightforward task. [PaperVision3D](http://www.papervision3d.org/), [Away3D](http://away3d.com/) or even the native [Stage3D API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html) in the Flash Player could get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize it and have full control over the content you better learn something from scratch: Alternativa3D, Away3D, Flare3D (quite yeasy), Minko.... Those are the most popular and depends on your needs.